# Why is the static value different from appender(log4j custom appender)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, static, log4j, appender

I make static variable like this in spring.

```java
public class A {
  private static final Map<String, Session> listMap = new HashMap<>();
  public static Map<String> getMap() { return this.listMap.values() }
  public static void addMap(String name, Session s) { return this.listMap.put(name, s) }
}
```

I save in service layer.

```java
@Slf4j
public class BService {
  public void addSession(String name, Session s) { 
    A.addMap("a", s);
    log.info("added!");
  }
}
```

After saving it, I used it in custom appender.(https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-custom-appender)

```java
@Plugin(
  name = "MapAppender", 
  category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, 
  elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
public class MapAppender extends AbstractAppender {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, LogEvent> eventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    protected MapAppender(String name, Filter filter) {
        super(name, filter, null);
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static MapAppender createAppender(
      @PluginAttribute("name") String name, 
      @PluginElement("Filter") Filter filter) {
        return new MapAppender(name, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        Map<> resultMap = A.getMap();
        send()
    }
}
```

However, when the appender's append() method is executed, `A.getMap()` return nothing(size 0). (A.getMap() return correctly in service layer.)
Why is the static value different?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listMap` is loaded when you call `addSession`so it is empty When `append()` method is called

Comment: But, I executed `addSession` before executing `append`.

Comment: where are you initialising `listMap`. Also put order of execution. From question, it seems  append is called before.

Comment: sorry, I edited content!.
I think like this. `bService.addSession()` exe. >> `A.listMap` init >> `A.listMap.put()` >> create log >> `MapAppender.append()` exe >> a.getMap()
So, I guess `listMap` has one entry before executing `MapAppender.append()` But listMap doesn't have any entry.....

Comment: getMap() can not return Map. It has to be `Session` as  map values are session

Comment: sorry getMap() reutrn sessoon. but A.getMap() didnt return anything even thought listmap has one session.(added when executed by A.addMap() )

Comment: use `listMap` instead of `this.listMap` in getMap() method. `this` refers to instance but listMap is static. I hope it helps

Comment: LOL..I've already tried, but I can't. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved problem!! When I was using `devtools`, it load class by seperate classloaders. That's why static variable wasn't shared!!